# Claims-based Windows login acting different on pre-IE10 and IE10

Tags: claims-based-auth, windows-authentication

I have a custom claims-based login page which works correctly in Firefox, Chrome, and IE 10. The login page is a standard "choose your login type" scenario that redirects to _windows for Windows logins.

When a user on IE9 or earlier chooses the Windows option and authenticates correctly, they are sent back to the login page. If they click the Windows link they again go back to the login page.

BUT, if we wait some time (don't know how much yet - 1 minute? 2 minutes?) then the Windows link takes them back to the original site. If the user puts the direct site URL in after authenticating, then that also works.

So it appears that the authentication and authorization is working, but that IE9 and earlier are waiting to figure that out somehow. I'm thinking it's a cookie timing issue of some sort but I can't figure out what it is.

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: This isn't normal behaviour, I use the same login configuration on several installations. It possibly is something to do with your login page. Trace what is happening with Fiddler2 turning on https decoding and take a look where the delay is. IE9 also has network tracing which you can use for taking a peak at what is being requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have posted this sooner. We figured out that on the production server, we had missed turning on the Claims to Windows Token Service. Not sure how that remotely maps to the behavior we were seeing, but that was what fixed it.